# Bigquery - Split function

Tags: python, google-bigquery

```
INSERT INTO
    "Table Name" (
    CurrentMonthlastDate, 
    MonthLastDate,
    yearmonth)
SELECT DISTINCT 
               (SELECT 
                DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS CurrentMonthlastDate),
                MonthLastDate, -- Get last day of month based on year.month
                yearmonth
                FROM
                "Table Name"
```

If the yearmonth value is '2018.04', how can I split this and find out the last day of the month?
Is this possible to split the value and insert the last day of month on the field 'MonthLastDate' while inserting reocords.

Answer (score 1):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y.%m',
          '2018.04'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

(SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(DATE(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAST(yearmonth AS STRING),'(.*)...') AS INT64),
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(CAST(yearmonth AS STRING),'.....(.*)') AS INT64), 01), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS **MonthLastDate**)

I got it myself. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE_SUB(
    DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y.%m', yearmonth), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ) MonthLastDate
```

You can test / play with above using below dummy data

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2018.04' AS yearmonth  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018.02'
)
SELECT 
  yearmonth, 
  DATE_SUB(
    DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y.%m', yearmonth), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ) MonthLastDate
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row yearmonth   MonthLastDate    
1   2018.04     2018-04-30   
2   2018.02     2018-02-28
```